# How best to use the order of one ArrayList to order another in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

For the Java app I am currently developing I am using an ID system, each ID being a unique string. I have two array lists, one is a an `ArrayList<String>` which holds just the IDs in the correct order, the other is an array list of objects which all have an .ID field. What is the best way to order the array list of objects so that their IDs are in the same order as the array list of String IDs?

Comment: This sounds painful. Have you considered re-designing your application to use a `HashMap`?

Comment: Define best way, big O, resource usage, etc

Comment: Or possibly use SortedMap? That sorts by the key-value, or you could use a Comparator.

Comment: @thkala TreeMap? TreeMap is ordered, but I don't know if the order of the ID's in the array can be calculated from the ID's.

Comment: @stryba by best way I mean "easy for me to write" probably because I'm only ever going to have 150 objects to sort at a time

Comment: Hi flea whale, do you have a natural ordering on those ID's?

Comment: @thkala no I didn't think of using using hashmap as only used these once before. I think I see it now, get rid of the ArrayList which is just of IDs and use a hashmap instead of the ArrayList of objects where the key is the order i want them to be in. then if I want to change the order just gotta switch each value in turn from one key to another...

Comment: though I will investigate these Comparators like @mindandmedia suggested... thanks all!

Comment: @owlstead I'm not certain what you mean by natural ordering... if you mean they are just in the order they appear in in the ArrayList, not ordered by any other logic, then yes

Comment: @fleawhale: it might help us if you told us what you are trying to do in broader terms. Without the large picture we are taking shots in the dark. For example, the code I provided could be exactly what you are asking for *in your question*, but it still seems to me that there is a fundamental design issue in your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put all objects in a HashMap using their ID as key, then run over second ID list and create new list of objects using ID and map. Should have a complexity around 2n -> n while not as resource friendly.

EDIT: to make it clear what I mean

```
List<String> idList;
List<ObjectWithID> objectList;

Map<String, ObjectWithID> helperMap=new HashMap<>();

//first O(n)
for (ObjectWithID o:objectList) {
  helperMap.put(o.ID, o);
}

int i=0;
//second O(n)
for (String id:idList) {
  objectList.set(i,helperMap.get(id));
  i++;
}
```

Assuming objectList and idList have the same size and same ids/object.IDs resp.

Comment: `List.set()` will fail if the list does not already have that index. Just use `add()` and lose the counter.

Comment: @thkala: thats why I said "Assuming objectList and idList have the same size and same ids/object.IDs resp."

Comment: Ah, right, I thought you created a new list. Objection withdrawn! +1

Comment: ahh with the example I now see, nice and simple and it works :) thanks @Stryba!

Comment: @fleawhale: but still, you might want to consider a redesign in general

Comment: yeah im redesigning now, but if i weren't id use yours ;)

Answer (score 2):

Allocate a 3rd list. An O(n^2) solution is to iterate over the list which has the ordered IDs. Inside this loop have another loop to find the object with its ID == current ID found in first loop/list. Extract this item and add it to the 3rd list:

```
for (ID in List<ID>)
    for (Item item in List<Item>){
        if (item.ID == ID){
            list3.add(item);
        }
    }
```

Horrible algorithm. I suggest you design your datastructures. Use a map or a comparator.

Comment: I've asked and it seems that there is no natural ordering of the ID's, other than the order in the list. Modded up as it is the only answer that does not assume natural ordering, and is simple to implement for a relatively small list.

Comment: ? most of the other answers don't assume natural ordering either

Comment: @stryba Even my comment assumes some compare to work on the ID, according to the asker, the only order we can rely on is the order in the array. That means comparators, SortedMap and such are out, and any answer incorporating those is wrong.

Comment: @owlstead: *unless* the comparator uses the order in the supplied ID list to do its job...

Comment: @thkala but the only way to reliably do that has the same order as Adrian's answer, so what's the point? It only adds complexity for a relatively small list.

Comment: @owlstead: there have been already at least two answers with better complexity than this that do not assume any natural ordering. Why do you believe that they won't work?

Comment: @thkala the accepted answer actually has a worse O than this simple idea :), then again, the O never mattered.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: You do not mention why you need to order those entries, but if it is only for ID matching purposes, you should probably redesign your application to use something along the lines of a HashMap or TreeMap from the beginning.*

Here's a possible solution, with `O(n)` complexity for the preparation and `O(n * log(n))` complexity for the actual sorting:

```
class MyEntry {
   public String id;
}

ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<MyEntry> entryList = new ArrayList<MyEntry>();

final HashMap<String, Integer> index = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

// Match each ID to its index
for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); ++i) {
    index.put(idList.get(i), i);
}

Collections.sort(entryList, new Comparator<MyEntry>() {
    public int compare(MyEntry o1, MyEntry o2) {
        return index.get(o1.id) - index.get(o2.id);
    }
});
```

*Disclaimer II: I have not actually run this code, but it should work...*

**EDIT:**

Just for the record, I focused way too much in finding a way to sort the original entry list. 
The [solution proposed by stryba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422033/507519) is simpler and faster for this particular use case.

My approach becomes advantageous only if future requirements make it necessary to quickly recover the index of an entry based on its ID.

Comment: What about the O(2n) resp. O(n) solution I presented?

Comment: @stryba: your solution is definitely faster - I may have focused a bit too much on sorting the existing list, as asked by the OP. On the other hand, it seems to me that whatever the OP is doing could use a redesign - I suspect that both of our solutions would be outperformed in that case...

Answer (score 1):

Just the general idea (no compiler)

```
public class MyListComparator implements Comparator<MyObject>{

    private ArrayList<String> ids;

    public MyListComparator(ArrayList<String> ids)
    {
        this.ids = ids;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        Integer i1 = ids.indexOf(o1.id);
        Integer i2 = ids.indexOf(o2.id);
        return i1.compareTo(i2);
    }
}
```

Comment: the complexity is over the top here

Comment: excited to see your response... my idea of responding is to move people forward

Comment: ok, none taken, still interested in your approach... there it is.

Answer (score 1):

Storing in 2 lists is not good design. If possible, you can refactor it and store in a Map. Depending on your requirements, you can decide what kind of Map implementation you need. For Ex: If you want to maintain the insertion order, you can go for LinkedHashMap.

If it is not possible to refactor/redesign, you can use the following example that I coded to test the sorting functionality. First off, I created a Person object with variables "id" and "name", as follows:

```
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And below is the Main class, where the sorting is implemented:

```
public class TwoLists {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        idList.add("1");
        idList.add("2");
        idList.add("3");
        idList.add("4");

        TwoLists twoLists = new TwoLists();

        personList.add(twoLists.createPerson("4", "Name4"));
        personList.add(twoLists.createPerson("2", "Name2"));
        personList.add(twoLists.createPerson("3", "Name3"));
        personList.add(twoLists.createPerson("1", "Name1"));

        System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
        for(Person person: personList) {
            System.out.println(person.getId());
        }

        Collections.sort(personList, twoLists.new TwoListsComparator(idList));

        System.out.println("After Sorting:");
        for(Person person: personList) {
            System.out.println(person.getId());
        }
    }

    private class TwoListsComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
        ArrayList<String> idList;

        private TwoListsComparator(ArrayList<String> idList) {
            this.idList = idList;
        }

        public int compare(Person person1, Person person2) {
            int index1 = idList.indexOf(person1.getId());
            int index2 = idList.indexOf(person2.getId());

            return Integer.valueOf(index1).compareTo(index2);
        }
    }

    private Person createPerson(String id, String name) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setId(id);
        p.setName(name);

        return p;
    }
}
```

In the above code, I created 2 lists : one for just id strings and other for Person objects. I'm then sorting the Person List by passing the idList to the comparator and comparing the index's.

Comment: your solution has a complexity of O(n ^ 2 * log(n)): the `indexOf()` method has linear complexity.

Comment: True, but it's just a worst-case option.

Comment: wow thanks, this is exactly what I asked for. id never heard of comparators before. cheers!

Comment: even if it is worst case scenario, they do happen you know

Comment: it also looks similar to @mindandmedia's solution, just more boilerplate

Comment: It's just a complete example, with compiling and testing!

Comment: @stryba you sound knowledgable, but I don't think you've grasped what flea whale actually was looking for: a simple answer that does not care about O. Supplying working code probably earned bchetty the answer.

Comment: @fleawhale: This is one of the worst answers. At best case, when the list is already sorted, you get O(n^2) complexity - for that result, you might as well use Adrian's answer and save yourself all this coding. If you value performance, my code is better and the solution by stryba is even more so for your particular case.

Comment: @owlstead: I don't care so much about whether bchetty earned that answer, as it is just a copy of another answer and it is one of the suboptimal ones (to put it mildly). And I understand the OP didn't care about O in this particular case but it is always a good idea to keep O in mind and therefore to encourage the OP to think about it.

Comment: @stryba: I agree with that last comment for sure ... your answer seems to the point as well, so I'll upvote that too

Comment: I don't understand why you folks are acting like kids, on a professional site? I saw the question, just tried working on an example and just posted the solution. Also, I posted that it's not the best solution and just a worst-case scenario. What's all this name-calling? It discourages the users to work on examples and post solutions!

Comment: @bchetty: I don't think we are acting like kids. I just tried to get the point across that the complexity of an algorithm should matter. It forces you to think about your problem more deeply. I appreciate your afford to provide an example though.

Comment: @bchetty: A *professional* should also accept healthy criticism and acknowledge when others offer better solutions. And they should also strive to prevent mistakes and misconceptions from propagating, which is what I (and others) was trying to do by asking fleawhale to change the accepted answer. I apologize if you felt uncomfortable but I doubt anyone here had anything personal against you.

Comment: Claiming that my answer is a copy is not offensive? BTW, I already replied back telling that it's a worst-case option!

Comment: @bchetty: 1. You admitted yourself that it is an implementation of the same idea. 2. And the best case is still O(n^2). When even my own answer at O(n * logn) worst case is suboptimal when compared to Stryba's answer, it would be remiss of me not to mention it.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a copy. I worked on it relaxedly, as I wanted to try if i can sort it with a comparator. Meanwhile someone else posted something similar without compiling/testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not sort both lists **separately** by ID.

Make one comparator that sorts your list of Strings, then make another comparator that compares the `.ID` field on your objects. Sort both lists separately, as long as both lists are 1-to-1 it should be fine.

Admittedly this is making a ton of assumptions about what you are trying to do. If this does not accomplish what you wanted, you should probably be a little more specific in your question about what you are trying to achieve.